# Swift 4: Button triggers the same action in another UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift4, indexpath

I have a cell with 2 buttons (for listening and speech recognition), label, and textfield. What I am trying to achieve is when the speech recognition button is selected the user speaks the content that is displayed in a label. 
My issue with this is that listening button works fine according to the indexPath.row, but the speaking button doesn't. As when it is active, the button in another cell is becoming active too. And it records the same in those cells.
[You can see the picture of what I am talking about here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcx3Z.png)

The methods for listening (which is audio synthesizer) and speech recognition are in the UITableViewCell. I have tried all the solutions I could find online, none of them did the trick. Have tried

```
protocol RepeatCellDelegate: class {
    func buttonTapped(cell: RepeatCell)
}
```

but the problem remains the same. Also, have created another project and instead of using the button to do speech recognition I just used direct textField input, still the same problem occurs.

Button in TableViewCell class:

```
@IBAction func speakButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
self.delegate?.buttonTapped(cell: self)
```

}

My `cellForRowAt indexPath`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RepeatCell") as! RepeatCell

cell.delegate = self

cell.conditionlabel.text = repeatTask[indexPath.row].conditionLabel

return cell
```

The buttonTapped function which detects the cell index and record speech input. It prints right cell index after the button is tapped, but the action gets triggered in another cell too.

```
func buttonTapped(cell: RepeatCell) {
guard let indexPath = self.repeatTV.indexPath(for: cell) else {
    return
}

cell.speakButton.isSelected = !cell.speakButton.isSelected

if (cell.speakButton.isSelected){
    self.recordAndRecognizeSpeech()
} else {
    audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    recognitionTask?.cancel()
}

print("Button tapped on row \(indexPath.row)")
```

}

// the speech input recognizer function:

```
// variables for speech recognizer
```

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en-US"))
let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?

// speech function
func recordAndRecognizeSpeech(){

```
let node = audioEngine.inputNode
let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
    self.request.append(buffer)
}
audioEngine.prepare()

do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    return print(error)
}

guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
    return
}
if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
    return
}

recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
    if result != nil { //
        if let result = result{
            let cell = self.repeatTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RepeatCell") as! RepeatCell
            let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            if cell.speakButton.isSelected == true {
                cell.userInput.text = bestString
            }

        }else if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
    }
})
```

}

I get data from a local JSON file and this is a model:

```
struct RepeatTask: Codable {
let name: String
let label: String
let conditionWord: String
```

}

Perhaps someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough code here to re-create your issue, in the future please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Unfortunately, no one can offer you a effective solution to help you resolve the issue if they cannot re-create the problem.

However I believe I understand what you are trying to accomplish:

1. A Model Object i.e. a `struct`.
2. A Protocol with a default implementation that is the same for all cells.
3. A `TableViewCell` class conforming to the protocol that calls the protocol's methods.
4. A TableViewDelegate and Datasource to manage the objects from 1.

Consider the following:

```
import UIKit

/// 1.
/// Data model for "Repeat Cell Objects"
struct RepeaterModel {
    var outputText:String?
    var inputAudio:Data?
}

/// 2.
/// Allows a cell to delegate listening and repeating (speaking)
protocol RepeatableCell {
    func listen()
    func speak()
}

// Extend your protocol to add a default implementation,
// that way you can just confrom to the protocol
// without implementing it every time, in every cell class.
extension RepeatableCell {
    func listen() {
        print("default implementation for listen")
    }

    func speak(){
        print("default implementation for speak")
    }

}



/// 3.
final class RepeatCell: UITableViewCell, RepeatableCell {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var model:RepeaterModel? {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.titleLabel.text = self.model?.outputText
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Views
    lazy var listenButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.setTitle("Listen", for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activateListen), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()

    lazy var speakButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.setTitle("Speak", for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activateSpeak), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .green
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.textColor = .black
        l.textAlignment = .center
        l.text = "No Text"
        return l
    }()

    //MARK: - Initializers
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //MARK: - Class Methods
    func setup() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(listenButton)
        self.contentView.addSubview(speakButton)
        self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        let spacing: CGFloat = 25.0

        //Listen top left
        listenButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        listenButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        listenButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        listenButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        // title label, center top.
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.listenButton.trailingAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.speakButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        //Speak top right
        speakButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: spacing).isActive = true
        speakButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing).isActive = true
        speakButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        speakButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func activateListen() {
        print("listen was pressed! on cell \(self.model?.outputText ?? "No Text")")
        /// The user wants to listen
        // call the delegate method..
        listen()
        // use self.model?.outputText
    }

    @objc func activateSpeak() {
        print("Speak was pressed! on cell \(self.model?.outputText ?? "No Text")")
        /// The user is speaking, record audio
        // call the delegate method..
        speak()
        //self.model?.inputAudio = somedata
    }
}



/// 4.
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Array of your model objects
    var objects:[RepeaterModel] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(RepeatCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Repeat")
        // create or fetch model objects
        let items = [
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "1st Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "2nd Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "3rd Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "4th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "5th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "6th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "8th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "9th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "10th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "11th Cell", inputAudio: nil),
            RepeaterModel(outputText: "12th Cell", inputAudio: nil)
        ]
        self.objects += items
    }


    //MARK: - TableView Methods

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // 25 top spacing + 50 view element width + 25 bottom spacing
        return 100.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Repeat") as? RepeatCell {
            cell.model = objects[indexPath.row]
            // other cell stuff
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Pressing "Listen" then "Speak" on each cell going downward yields this output:

[image: View Hierarchy with output]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and writing all the code above, unfortunately, it doesn't work. It does not play the audio, neither it's recording. I have updated my question with some more information about the previous method I have used. Please have a look at it if you have time, thanks.

Comment: Or maybe I am doing the speak() and listen() functions inside RepeatCell extension wrong, as normally to assigning bestString (speech recognition) to another variable or textview I need to make if statement for example: if (speakButton.isActiove) { inputTextView.text = bestString }. But the problem is that I can't use speakButton in the extension. Maybe there's another way of achieving this, I need to figure out.

Comment: you can pass self through the protocol methods and return a value to assign to your textview. i.e. `listen(_ cell: UITableViewCell) -> String?` and then `textView.text = self.listen(self)` within buttons method. (activateListen). Most likely the issue you where having is because of the line `let cell = self.repeatTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RepeatCell") as! RepeatCell` in you `recognitionTask`, you should reference the cell itself, rather than dequeuing another cell.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to find the way of how to reference the cell itself. I assume the problem of the cells getting the same action caused by the button itself when it goes to .isSelected state. As I added some other buttons that just have to perform simple things (listening, changing the colour) they work according to the index path. Anyway, I am still quite new in swift. The example you gave above is good as well, it gave me several insights of how the things are done. I'll use it in the coming days, will tell you how it went. Thanks for your effort mate, much appreciated.